# unix_timestamp date and time difference

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have stored three essential timestamps and times into my database table, format as follows:

```
mysql> select receivedtime, requesttime, sla from table;
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| receivedtime        | requesttime         | sla      |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2013-05-26 22:37:04 | 2013-05-26 12:37:04 | 02:59:59 |
| 2013-05-26 14:36:44 | 2013-05-21 12:39:09 | 72:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to put a few conditions like below:

```
difference = (receivedtime - requesttime);

if [difference <= sla] 
{
   show meet
} else {
   show don't meet
}
```

legend:

```
receivedtime [timestamp] as because days 
requesttime [timestamp] as because days 
sla [time] as because hour
```

I have checked `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` of `mysql, strtotime()` of `php` and few other tries.

I also have checked several threads @ stackoverflow.com, but I can't find proper solution.

Any ideas...!

Comment: What do you mean by `meet`. What do you want in `meet`

Comment: Why did `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` not work?

Comment: I mean by `meet` is YES/OKAY and `don't meet` is NO/NOT OKAY, I think mine execution was right. But, I was confused with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. Now I am confirmed that was really right query to see @CORRUPT answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT receivedtime, 
       requesttime,
       CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, requesttime, receivedtime) < TIME_TO_SEC(sla) 
            THEN 'meet' ELSE 'don\'t meet' END sla
  FROM table1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a3e/5)** demo

Answer (score 2):

Check [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) functions:

```
SELECT
    `receivedtime`,
    `requesttime`,
    `sla`,
    (SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `requesttime`, `receivedtime`)) < `sla`) as `meet`
FROM
    `table`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting from your database like this ...

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, receivedtime, requesttime) as difference, TIME_TO_SEC(sla) as slasecs from table
```

and then you can do your.

```
if [difference <= sla]
{
   show meet
} 
else 
{
   show don't meet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a datetime field, not a timestamp field. You should start with reading up on what a timestamp is.

you can figure out the difference by converting to timestamp then subtracting.

```
$recieved = strtotime($res['receivedtime']);
$requested = strtotime($res['requesttime']);
$difference = $recieved - $requested;
if($difference <= $sla){
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in SQL

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(receivedtime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requesttime)) AS difference FROM table
```

it gives you the difference in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`requesttime`,`receivedtime`) as timeDiff FROM `table` 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`requesttime`,`receivedtime`) > TIME_TO_SEC(`sla`)
```

[SEE SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcb1cc/1)

You can find relevant in [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: Whay everything is varchar rather than timestamp

Comment: @Deonia nothing it was just dummy setup for testing .if that is reason to downvote I can surely correct that ..